# (Anybody, please? I tried figuring it out but still stuck) Strategy Entry when Multiple Conditions are met

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have tried whatever I can but cannot figure out how to do this. I have no experience in coding but I am decently proficient in excel and know VBA to some extent, so somehow I manage to wiggle my way with different coding languages for different requirements. I can say that I am good at Googling, so I just google what I exactly want and get the answers for the task in any language that I am working on. And then simply copy paste the solutions with the adjustments that are specific to my task. But can't figure this one out, and I have googled different questions and searched for solutions on all the result pages. Didn't get lucky as usual. Just started with Pine Code last week.

I have the following query.

So I have an indicator that runs from 0 - 100. It can stay at 100 or 0 for multiple bars.
I want to do the following -

When the indicator reaches 100, I want to find the closing price of the bar. Then until it stays at 100, this condition should be open (**this is the first condition**). Then once the indicator value goes below 98, I want to find the closing price of the bar (**this is the second condition**). If the closing price of the bar when the indicator went below 98 was higher than the closing price when the indicator reached 100 the first time, then a strategy.long will execute.

If the above two conditions are met but the closing price on condition1 was higher than the closing price on condition 2, then a strategy.short will execute.

When the indicator reaches 0, I want to find the closing price of the bar. Then until it stays at 0, this condition should be open (**this is the first condition**). Then once the indicator value goes above 2, I want to find the the closing price of the bar (**this is the second condition**). If the closing price of the bar when the indicator went above 2 was higher than the closing price when the indicator reached 0 the first time, then a strategy.long will execute.

If the above two conditions are met but the closing price on condition1 was higher than the closing price on condition 2, then a strategy.short will execute.

Also, I want to add a limit of 0.8% on the price when the startegy is long/short.

If you read all of this, thank you for your time.

Hoping you can help me with a solution.

Thank You once again, Cheers! :)

```
 This is my code (it currently is an indicator but I want a strategy).-
```

```
mom = ta.mom(close,100)
percentile = (ta.percentrank(mom, 100))

x = false
if percentile == 100
    x:=true

if percentile < 99 and percentile >98
    x:=false

    
plotshape(percentile, title = "Buy", style = shape.arrowup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.green, text = "Buy", textcolor = color.green, size = size.large)
```

It resulted in multiple buy signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after two days, I finally did it. The results aren't the way I expected them to be, but that doesn't matter because I learnt something new and this has opened up a lot of different other ideas to me. Also, I didn't figure it out on my own, I had posted the same query on the pinescript subreddit and a fellow redditor helped with a part of the code and I took it from there. Here is the [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/pinescript/comments/x9td1o/comment/inzwvr7/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

And here is my full code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("percentile indicator", overlay = true)

mom = ta.mom(close,100)
percentile = (ta.percentrank(mom, 100))

c1 = 0.0
c1 := nz(c1[1])
c1 := (percentile == 100 and percentile[1] < 100) ? close : c1

c2 = 0.0
c2 := nz(c2[1])
c2 := (percentile[1] == 100 and percentile < 100) ? close : c2

event = 0
event := nz(event[1])
event := percentile == 100 ? 1 : event
event := event ==1 and percentile < 100 ? 2 : event

long = event == 2 and c2 > c1 ? 1 : 0
short = event == 2 and c2 < c1 ? 1 : 0

event := event == 2 ? 0 : event

plotshape(long, title = "Long", style = shape.labelup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.green, text = "Long", textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(short, title = "Short", style = shape.labelup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.red, text = "Short", textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)


c3 = 0.0
c3 := nz(c3[1])
c3 := (percentile == 0 and percentile[1] > 0) ? close : c3

c4 = 0.0
c4 := nz(c4[1])
c4 := (percentile[1] == 0 and percentile > 0) ? close : c4

event1 = 0
event1 := nz(event1[1])
event1 := percentile == 0 ? 1 : event1
event1 := event1 == 1 and percentile > 0 ? 2 : event1

long1 = event1 == 2 and c4 > c3 ? 1 : 0
short1 = event1 == 2 and c4 < c3 ? 1 : 0

event1 := event1 == 2 ? 0 : event1

plotshape(long1, title = "Long", style = shape.labelup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.green, text = "Long", textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)
plotshape(short1, title = "Short", style = shape.labelup, location = location.belowbar, color = color.red, text = "Short", textcolor = color.white, size = size.tiny)
```

EDIT - the above was an indicator and below is the strategy with limits and stops.

```
//@version=5
strategy("ABC")

mom = ta.mom(close,100)
percentile = (ta.percentrank(mom, 100))

c1 = 0.0
c1 := nz(c1[1])
c1 := (percentile == 100 and percentile[1] < 100) ? close : c1

c2 = 0.0
c2 := nz(c2[1])
c2 := (percentile[1] == 100 and percentile < 100) ? close : c2

event = 0
event := nz(event[1])
event := percentile == 100 ? 1 : event
event := event ==1 and percentile < 100 ? 2 : event

long = event == 2 and c2 > c1 ? 1 : 0
short = event == 2 and c2 < c1 ? 1 : 0

longprice = ta.valuewhen(long,close,0)
shortprice = ta.valuewhen(short,close,0)
limitlong = longprice * 1.008
stoplong = longprice * 0.992
limitshort = shortprice * 0.992
stopshort = shortprice * 1.008

event := event == 2 ? 0 : event

if long
    strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Long Exit","Enter Long", limit = limitlong, stop = stoplong)
if short
    strategy.entry("Enter Short", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("Short Exit","Enter Short",limit = limitshort, stop = stopshort)

c3 = 0.0
c3 := nz(c3[1])
c3 := (percentile == 0 and percentile[1] > 0) ? close : c3

c4 = 0.0
c4 := nz(c4[1])
c4 := (percentile[1] == 0 and percentile > 0) ? close : c4

event1 = 0
event1 := nz(event1[1])
event1 := percentile == 0 ? 1 : event1
event1 := event1 == 1 and percentile > 0 ? 2 : event1

long1 = event1 == 2 and c4 > c3 ? 1 : 0
short1 = event1 == 2 and c4 < c3 ? 1 : 0

long1price = ta.valuewhen(long1,close,0)
short1price = ta.valuewhen(short1,close,0)
limit1long = long1price * 1.008
stop1long = long1price * 0.992
limit1short = short1price * 0.992
stop1short = short1price * 1.008

event1 := event1 == 2 ? 0 : event1

if long1
    strategy.entry("Enter Long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("Long Exit","Enter Long", limit = limit1long, stop = stop1long)
if short1
    strategy.entry("Enter Short", strategy.short)
    strategy.exit("Short Exit","Enter Short",limit = limit1short, stop = stop1short)
```